# Error when installing cloud_firestore flutter for Android

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, plugins

It's been hours that I'm trying to install cloud_firestore to my flutter app. I have installed many plugins, so I don't know what's wrong.
This is what I did:

I opened pubspec.yaml, I added cloud_firestore:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.0
```

Then in the terminal, I write:

```
flutter pub get
```

When I compile the code on my Android (both emulator and real device), I get this error:
[image]

This is the file https://easyupload.io/1zsfc0

I tried to understand the error, but I don't

Any hints? what problem could be?

Comment: Try to add the command --no-shrink when you build your apk

Answer (score 0):

In your android/app/build.gradle.
You need to add multiDexEnabled.

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
```